# Zend Framework: Hide navigation item in menu by show in breadcrumbs

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation

i am using `Zend_Navigation` i want to show the nav item in the breadcrumbs but hide it in my menu, how can i do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are many choices, e.g.

- You may set `visible` parameter to false (eg. in xml config file), then use `setRenderInvisible(true/false)` on the navigation helper,
- You may use separate containers,
- You may modify the container on the fly (`getContainer()`, `getItemBy()`…)

Answer (score 4):

When using an XML config file, use an integer instead of a boolean value:

```
<visible>0</visible>
```

An issue has already been logged for this problem [here](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-10146).